# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager;

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I read many posts about the error `javax/transaction/TransactionManager`, but none of those solutions fix my problem.

First thing to say is that I get that error when I deploy my web-application (made with Spring MVC and Hibernate) on the server. On my computer, with Eclipse and Tomcat 7 everything works.

Second thing to say is that on that server I have another web-application that's running under tomcat `/root` folder (this is a simple java application, that DOESN'T use neither Spring mvc nor Hibernate). The new application that i'm trying to deploy is running under another folder called `/prova`.

These are all the libraries of my application
 [image]

Plus, according to what I read on some posts, I added to my lib folder:

1) jta-3.1.2.2.jar

2) hibernate3.3.1-jta-1.1.jar

3) javax.transaction.jar

In my xml file I have this bean that defines the transaction manager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Something strange is that in the server log the exact error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager;
```

There's a **L** before `javax/transaction/TransactionManager`

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry with the "**L**", it just defines that the following is an object. You can find other letters :

```
BaseType
B     byte (signed byte)
C     char (Unicode character)
D     double (double-precision floating-point value)
F     float (single-precision floating-point value)
I     int (integer)
J     long (long integer)
L<classname>;     reference (an instance of class <classname>)
S     short (signed short)
Z     boolean (true or false)
[     reference (one array dimension )
```

To come back to your problem, did you define your transaction manager whith something close to this :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

HibernateTransactionManager is an implementation of javax.transaction.TransactionManager

Comment: Hi man, I edited mypost, adding the bean of my transaction manager.

Comment: On your server, did you check that the libs in the classpath are the same than on your computer ? HibernateTransactionManager is provided by spring-orm, so it should be in the war. Maybe you should try adding spring-orm in tomcat external classpath to check that the one in the war is not skipped mysteriously ???

Comment: It came out the problem was the wrong name of the database. Now I don't get that error anymore. Thank you.

Comment: please edit the question so that people know that you have found an answer to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

where is spring-data jars? It looks like spring-data-commons. Please, spend some time to learn how to use maven or gradle. It will save a lot of your time.

Answer (score -1):

you must add this dependency It is work

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```